# Multiple issues; Kernel panic, Random Crashing, Unable to install/ remove programs

Tags: installation, kernel, launcher, unity-dash

So i have been having issues pretty much since installation.

I have 12.10 installed on an HP Pavillion DV6000.

It goes into Kernel Panic (i think) almost every time i interact with the Dash, and sometimes when i interact with the launcher.

i cannot install or remove programs, it once popped a message up saying that something was broken, the program index or something, and gave me a line of code to run in the launcher to "fix it at first", but i couldnt copy it, and when i went to manually type it in the terminal, it disappeared...

also, it crashes whenever it feels like.

and sometimes it takes 3-4 start ups to get it to actually run when i turn it on, which is quite frustrating because the battery can only keep this thing running for about 5 minutes once its unplugged.

This computer is driving me insane! I can barely do anything with it, and i'm too broke to buy a new computer.

somebody, please, help me..

Comment: I made an answer for you but I have to handed to you, I mean a dv6000 in 2013 without changing a single piece. You REALLY put a lot of love on that baby.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I am pretty sure the problem is not Ubuntu and might be something worse. I had an HP DV6000 (Sold the laptop about a month back) and that puppy was running fine with 12.10.

The problem I encountered with that laptop (Just in case I had the one with the Intel video card) is that, since it was pretty old by now, the same issue you mentioned happened to me but on Ubuntu 11.10, at the end it was not Ubuntu but the cables that connect from the Power button to the Quick buttons and the hard drive.

It is basically a ribbon that connects that, that somehow fails "sometimes" and "sometimes" doesn't. If you happen to hold pressure on top of the left part of the keyboard or nearby or above the touchpad and suddenly it does not work or it does work and does not fail, then it is the ribbon.

This is the quickest one I found: http://www.ebay.com/itm/HP-DV6000-DV9000-KOTL-E220709-AWM-20798-80C-60V-RIBBON-SWITCH-CABLE-POWER-BUTTON-/400313605577?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5d348cddc9 (Was looking in Amazon but that place sucks in having a better advanced filter). To change it there are steps to do that and is not hard. Will take you if it is the first time you work on the laptop between 15 to 20 minutes.

I would suggest to actually remove the 2 ribbons it has right now and change both for the new ones.

The battery is another problem since the original one will start failing (At least failing to charge) after 2-3 years. I bought a newer, bigger one before selling it. but when I sold the laptop I included the older one but warned the buyer that it would only last about 10 to 15 "Real" minutes. I say real since Windows or Ubuntu will say an hour.

I am sorry to give you such bad news about this, at least you have the solution which I had to live with for about 5 months until giving up and trying to solve the problem myself (In my country it is tough to find a way to fix this laptop and they were charging me about 200$ for something that actually costs 50$ including labor). For you it will cost less than 10$ since with that you can buy the 2 cables. I even saw one guy selling 4 of them for 10$.

Hope you solve the problem with this since I know how it feels. That laptop is the best one I have had so far.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds more like either a failing hard drive than anything else. One way to check would be to use an Ubuntu LiveCD, and if that behaves normally, then it is most likely the hard drive. Using a LiveCD means that the hard drive is not being accessed, which takes that piece of hardware out of the equation.

Another thing that makes me suspect the Hard Drive is that laptop hard drives generally do not (in my pretty comprehensive, though anecdotal) experience last a very long time, and yours is right about the age where they would start failing.

Try the liveCD, if that works fine then you may want to look at backing up as much as you can before replacing the HDD.

Otherwise it is probably some other hardware fault which requires a more indepth diagnosis.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot man, i appreciate it. i'll have to try that, but  guess i might as well just start saving for a new laptop..